# How to start opennms?

Tags: opennms

I installed opennms on RHEL6 operating....i have installed all dependencies and when i am running this command

```
/sbin/service opennms start
```

then the opennms is running but i am not able to open the opennms page on my web the adress that I have been using is:

```
http://192.168.1.15:8980/opennms/
```

can any one please help me regarding this.

I have already edited iptables and the id that i have given there is 192.168.1.00/24
I have also edited discovery-configuration.xml with the same ip.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check that the OpenNMS service is bound to either all interfaces, or the interface you expect it to be bound to:

```
netstat -na | grep 8980
```

You should see something similar to the following, assuming a wildcard bind:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8980                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      13504/java
```

Next, make sure that IPtables really isn't the culprit by checking the relevant logs (if you've configured IPtables to log, that is), or by temporarily disabling IPtables (after you've considered the security ramifications of doing so, i.e. whether or not you can accept the risk of being without a firewall for a minute or two).

I don't believe that OpenNMS Discovery has anything to do with your access problem, so ignore discovery-configuration.xml for the moment.